# No Package.xml Found In Destructive MDAPI Deployment

Tags: vs-code, package.xml, mdapi, mdapideploy

I've already looked at the existing questions and made sure of the following:

1. Only package.xml & destructiveChanges.xml are in the folder I'm trying to deploy.
2. package.xml is empty outside of the version

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

3. The items in destructiveChanges.xml exist in the org I'm trying to delete them from.

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>IPTProjectCategoryTypePicklist</members>
        <members>IPTProjectCategoryTypePicklistTest</members>
        <members>IPTProject_FetchMultipleRecords</members>
        <members>IPTProject_FetchMultipleRecordsTEST</members>
        <members>IPTProject_RequiredDocumentation</members>
        <members>IPTProject_RequiredDocumentationTest</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

4. The folder is at the root of the project.
5. Updated SFDX CLI

I've tried deploying it by the directory and by a zip of the directory. The same package.xml can be used to retrieve items from ORG via the VSC UI fine. I've only been able to find a bug from 2015 about this issue.
Here's a picture of the attempts:
[image: Picture of VSC terminal attempting to deploy a destructive package by directory and then by zip]

Is there anything I'm missing/overlooking? Did I format the command improperly? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that the complaint is about empty `package.xml`, so, I guess you cannot have a deployment to delete only, using the destructive changes xml. When I used it I always had something to deploy and some components to remove.

Comment: @JefersonChaves other documentation I've read says that ``package.xml`` has to be empty but I'll try to add something random to it to see if it'll go. It'd be a bit upsetting if I have to deploy something random every time I want to clean up an apex class from production.

Comment: @JefersonChaves No, you can have an empty package.xml (given the example here).

Comment: Give me just a couple minutes while I do some testing, MadameEvil. I'll be right back with you.

Comment: @sfdcfox I feel that Metada API supports that (in fact remember using that with ANT) but sfdx mdapi is not honoring, yet: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/188

Comment: @JefersonChaves Nope, I can't seem to replicate the problem. It works for me.

Comment: Were you be able to resolve the issue, I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be a problem in the latest version. I've tried the following:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f manifest.zip -w 10
```

And:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d manifest/ -w 10
```

Both worked out well, and deleted the file in question. I also tried it with and without the normal XML header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Absolutely nothing I've tried has resulted in this error.

It might just be a problem with how PowerShell works, or maybe you have a space in your file path (e.g. `C:\Users\Brian Fear\workspace` has been known to cause problems in some commands/versions).

The only real suggestion I have is to try and move your project to a space without spaces, such as `C:\workspace\myproject\`.

Comment: Just to make sure since SFDX has lied to me about being updated before, this is the version I'm on ``sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on the latest version: 7.100.0-9d243d8`` does that match up with the version you're running?

Comment: @MadameEvil `sfdx-cli/7.101.0 win32-x64 node-v14.6.0` is what I'm on. It may be worth noting that I use the npm package `npm install -g sfdx-cli` and not the binary installer. I am aware that the bin install has had occasional issues, so I prefer the npm version instead.

Comment: I tried from bash shell instead of power shell to the same effect. I reinstalled via npm and still can't seem to get the version you're on. I wonder if it's a difference in the node versions causing issues? ``sfdx-cli/7.100.0 win32-x64 node-v16.0.0`` I may try on a different machine with a fresh instal of CLI and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same but after removing the parameter -l RunLocalTests it works ok. I guess this parameter expects something in the package.xml